# Foundation Framework: How can I get multiple links in a mobile drop-down to be horizontally aligned and not stacked?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm creating a website using Zurb's Foundation Framework for the first time , and I love it so far but I'm stuck on this one annoying thing! I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious or not but I'd love it if you could help me!

Basically, in the desktop version, I have several social media icons that display above the top bar navigation, aligned one after the other horizontally. In the mobile version, I've hidden the top set of social media icons, and revealed a second set below the list of more important navigation items so that they aren't popping up first in the menu drop-down. This all works fine, my problem is that since the social media icons are all very small, I'd like them all to be in one row, horizontally aligned like in the desktop version, but I can only get them to display vertically.

**I've tried having them in a single < li > element, and I tried using nonbreakable spaces, but neither thing worked. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?**

**By the way here is the website I'm working on: http://cakebattermusic.com**

Just to be clear, here is how I want it to pop up: (assume F, T, I are facebook twitter instagram)

```
HOME
CONTACT
WHATEVER
F T I
```

Here is how it pops up now:

```
HOME
CONTACT
WHATEVER
F
T
I
```

**Is it possible to maybe list LI elements horizontally in only PART of a list and not the whole list? That would solve the problem but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that or if it's possible.**

Here's the html:

```
<!-- /////////////////////// HEADER ////////////////// -->

  <!-- HEADER SECTION -->
<div class="contain-to-grid header-section">

<!-- TOPBAR SECTION -->
<nav class="top-bar important-class" data-topbar>

<!-- TITLE AREA & LOGO -->
<ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
        <img src="img/logo.jpg" width="100px" alt="" id="logo-image">
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>menu</span></a></li>
</ul> <!-- END TITLE AREA & LOGO -->

<!-- MENU ITEMS -->
<section class="top-bar-section">
   <ul class="right">
       <div id="hidden"> <!-- hidden in mobile view -->
        <li><a href="http://facebook.com/cakebattermusic" target="_blank"><img src="img/facebook.00_png_srz" border="0"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://twitter.com/cakebattermusic" target="_blank"><img src="img/twitter.00_png_srz" border="0"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://instagram.com/cakebattermusic" target="_blank"><img src="img/instagram.00_png_srz" border="0"></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://cakebattermusic.tumblr.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/tumblr.gif" border="0" width="20px"></a></li>
       </div>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <ul class="right">
        <li><a href="/index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bio.html">BIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="/music.html">MUSIC</a></li>
        <li><a href="/videos.html">VIDEOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tour.html">TOUR</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        <div id="hidden2"> <!-- hidden in desktop view -->
        <li><a href="http://facebook.com/cakebattermusic" target="_blank"><img src="img/facebook.00_png_srz" border="0"></a>
        <a href="http://twitter.com/cakebattermusic" target="_blank"><img src="img/twitter.00_png_srz" border="0"></a>
        <a href="http://instagram.com/cakebattermusic" target="_blank"><img src="img/instagram.00_png_srz" border="0"></a>
        <a href="http://cakebattermusic.tumblr.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/tumblr.gif" border="0" width="20px"></a></li>
       </div>
    </ul>
    <br>

</section> <!-- END MENU ITEMS -->
```

Header CSS:

```
/*
   HEADER SECTION
   ==========================================================================     */
.header-section {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  min-width: 100%; }

.contain-to-grid {
  background-color: #fff; 
}

.header-fill {
  background: #fff;
  height: 120px; }
  .header-fill .tablet-mobile-logo img {
    padding-top: 30px; }

.padding-on-my-header {
  padding: 17px 0.9375rem 62px 0.9375rem; }
  .padding-on-my-header ul.title-area img {
    margin: -5px 0 0 0; }

.full-width {
  min-width: 100%; }

p {
  line-height: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 30px; }

/*
   TOPBAR NAVGATION
   ==========================================================================     */


.top-bar {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0.9375rem 90px 0.9375rem;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0.1s; }
  .top-bar ul.title-area img {
    margin: -10px 0 0 0; }
  .top-bar .top-bar-section ul {
        background: #fff; }
    .top-bar .top-bar-section ul li a:not(.button), .top-bar .top-bar-section ul li.active a:not(.button) {
      background: #fff;
       line-height: 30px;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 5px 0 0 0;
      text-transform: uppercase; }
    .top-bar .top-bar-section ul li a:not(.button):hover {
      background: #fff;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #c3c3c3;
      color: #333; }
    .top-bar .top-bar-section ul li.active a:not(.button) {
      border-bottom: 2px solid #c3c3c3;
      color: #333; }
      .top-bar .top-bar-section ul li.active a:not(.button):hover {
         background: #fff; }
    .top-bar .top-bar-section ul li {
      margin-left: 30px; }
      .top-bar .top-bar-section ul li a {
        color: #333; }
  .top-bar .top-bar-section ul li:hover:not(.has-form) > a {
    color: #333; }
  .top-bar .top-bar-section li ul.dropdown {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    color: #333; }
    .top-bar .top-bar-section li ul.dropdown li {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px; }
  .top-bar .top-bar-section li ul.dropdown li a:not(.button):hover, .top-bar .top-bar-section li ul.dropdown li a:not(.button) {
    background: #fff;
    color: #222;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 20px -4px 40px 45px; }
  .top-bar .top-bar-section ul.dropdown li:hover:not(.has-form) > a:not(.button) {
    background: #fff;
    color: #222; }
  .top-bar .has-dropdown > a:after {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) transparent transparent;
    margin-top: -5px; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=scss.css.map */



#hidden{
    display: inherit;
}

#hidden2{
    display: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    #hidden{
        display: none;
    }
    #hidden2{
        display: inherit;
    }
  .top-bar {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: none; }
    .top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a {
      color: #222; }
      .top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a:after {
        box-shadow: 0 10px 0 1px #222, 0 16px 0 1px #222, 0 22px 0 1px #222; }
    .top-bar ul.title-area img {
      margin: -2px 0 0;
      width: 50px; }
    .top-bar .top-bar-section ul {
      background: #333; }
      .top-bar .top-bar-section ul li {
        margin-left: 0; }
      .top-bar .top-bar-section ul li > a {
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 0;
        font-size: 0.9rem; }
      .top-bar .top-bar-section ul li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button) {
        background: none;
        color: #222;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin-top: 0; }
        .top-bar .top-bar-section ul li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button):hover {
          background: #fff;
          color: #222;
          margin-top: 0; }
      .top-bar .top-bar-section ul li.active:not(.has-form) a:not(.button) {
        background: #fff;
        color: #222;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        margin-top: 0; }
        .top-bar .top-bar-section ul li.active:not(.has-form) a:not(.button):hover {
           background: white;
          margin-top: 0; }

  .top-bar.padding-on-my-header ul.title-area img {
    margin: 5px 13px 0;
    width: 35px; }

  .top-bar.expanded {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: none; }
    .top-bar.expanded .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a {
      color: #222; }
      .top-bar.expanded .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a:after {
        box-shadow: 0 10px 0 1px #222, 0 16px 0 1px #222, 0 22px 0 1px #222; }
 }



/* ////// END HEADER //////*/
```

Comment: Can you create a [Codeply](http://www.codeply.com)?

Comment: @ManojKumar Hmmm ok I'll try! If it helps the website I'm working on is at http://www.cakebattermusic.com (only the index page is updated with the code above)

Comment: It is already horizontal now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a little CSS. I use the Chrome inspector to find the right selectors to target.

example - http://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/KpXEVe?editors=110

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 40.063em) {

  .top-bar-section ul.social-icons li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```